# Swift ios9 is there any fix to UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance causing error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, ios9

I am getting the following error:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

After looking around it seems to be caused by:

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in **Info.plist**

Soruce: [apple dev forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683)

When I read through the thread I see a apple dev respond with:
*- "You may ignore this warning."*

But is there any fix to this beside removing UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance from the Info.plist file?
I need it in order to keep my status bar white in my VC's, and I dont like to just ignore a warning.

Comment: hopefully they fix this soon[...](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683)

Answer (score 0):

No. There is currently no fix for this. This is a bug and will be fixed at some point in the future. As you say, you can ignore this, I wouldn't waste any time on this if I were you.